# JavaScript - Quiz RadioButtons and Form validation

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get the button grade me work when I click on it? It should provide with an alert box displaying all the score for each correct answer. See the code below:

```
 !DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src = "quiz.js"> </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend> Question 1 </legend>
                    He _____ it. <br>
                    <input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q1" id = "q"> don't like <br>
                    <input type = "radio" value = "right" name = "q1" id = "q"> doesn't like <br>
                    <input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q1" id = "q"> don't likes <br>
                </fieldset> <br>

                <fieldset>
                    <legend> Question 2 </legend>
                    They _____ here very often. <br>
                    <input type = "radio" value = "right" name = "q2" id = "q"> don't come <br>
                    <input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q2" id = "q"> doesn't comes <br>
                    <input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q2" id = "q"> don't doesn't come <br>
                </fieldset> <br>

                <fieldset>
                    <legend> Question 3 </legend>
                    John and Mary _____ twice last week. <br>
                    <input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q3" id = "q"> comes <br>
                    <input type = "radio" value = "wrong" name = "q3" id = "q"> come <br>
                    <input type = "radio" value = "right" name = "q3" id = "q"> coming <br>
                </fieldset> <br>

    function validate(){
        var cor = 0;
    var radios = document.getElementById('q');
      for(var i = 1; i < radios.length; i++){
          if (radios[i].checked == true && radios[i].value == "right") {
            cor++
          }
      }
    }alert("Correct " + cor);
```

Comment: i shall correct ur english first. Question 3 : John and Mary came twice last week. I should be came , not coming. I will work on your code , give me some time

Comment: Lol.. It is an MCQ type question :p That's why we have some english errors too !

Comment: Do you want to display the score when a button is clicked or when the user checks the last radiobutton

Comment: I want to display the score when the user click the 'Grade Me' button. 
It should give an alert box together with the scores and the wrong results

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your HTML

```
<button id="results" onclick="display()">
Show me the answers!
</button>
```

Javascript

```
var cor=0;
function validate(){

    var radios = document.getElementById('q');
      for(var i = 1; i < radios.length; i++){
          if (radios[i].checked == true && radios[i].value == "right") {
            cor++
          }
      }
}
function display(){
    alert(cor);}
```

Comment: Oh forgot to add parenthesis in onClick

Comment: @user3545953 try it out now